# Will Shield encrypt the data in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

When Shield is installed, will the data indexed into Elasticsearch be encrypted? Or just the access needs to be authenticated and authorized?

What if someone with access to the server disable shield plugin and restart elasticsearch, will that expose all the indexed data on the network?

Comment: Only the node-to-node and client-to-node communications are encrypted, not the data itself.

Comment: Thanks. Are there any solution for data encryption? Shall we do it by ourselves? We are using Spring Data btw.

Comment: If you're encrypting the data, you won't be able to index/search it in ES, hence losing the benefits of using ES in the first place.